# Change datagrid column values in DatagridCombobox selectedindexchanged event

Tags: winforms

I have a datagrid with DatagridComboboxcolumn as one of the column in winforms.
Combobox is contain two items Y,N.
If user select Y,I need to change the value for the two columns of same row.
Same thing will happen when User select "N".

I have tried to register  ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged as follows.

But not able to get the row index or coulmn index for the selected row and change the values of the same row columns.

Please help me asap.

```
 private void gridTesr_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;           
            if(combo != null)
            {
                // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid 

                // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.

                combo.SelectedIndexChanged -=new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

                // Add the event handler. 

                combo.SelectedIndexChanged +=new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Can't you use the DataGridView's *CurrentRow* / *CurrentCell* properties?

Comment: Yes,I can use currentrow/currentcell property.But I'm not able to get correct value of combobox after I selected item in selectionchanged event. Is there anything wrong with my event registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring your own method to handle the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
private void gridTesr_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;           
    if(combo != null)
    {
          // Remove an existing event-handler, if present
          combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= this.MyComboEventHandler;

          // Add the event handler
          combo.SelectedIndexChanged += this.MyComboEventHandler;
    }
}

private void MyComboEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myValue = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
    DataGridViewCell cell = gridTesr.CurrentCell;

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The current ComboBox resides in the Row {0} and Column {1} and it currently has the {3} value.",
          cell.RowIndex, cell.ColumnIndex, myValue));
}
```